# Looking for extension similar to GitLense for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

On my private projects I am using Git. I have installed GitLense for Visual Studio Code, which is awesome. I can click on a line, and see who changed it when within which changeset. See red arrows where I have deleted code and so on.

I have a VS2017 project using azure DevOps. I have read about CodeLense, which does not apply on my C++ projects, even in C# it is barely helpful.

Does someone know a similar extension here?

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could install the extension [Code Compare](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.CodeCompare) to check the file changes.

Also, if you are using Azure DevOps and clone the repo local, we could open Team Explorer->Changes->Actions->View History->select commit and right-click->View Commit Details to check the changes, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/review-history?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#retrieve-files) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to installing VS Code extensions in ADS. Not the simplest but it gets the job done. I'd also like to acknowledge that this is a VERY imperfect method which could skip some important extension updates that could still work with the outdated VS Code version underlying ADS.

1. In ADS, select `Help` then `About` and note the version of VS Code. Find the month/year in which that version was published in the [VS Code update docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates). For me, this was version 1.67 which was published ~April 2022.
2. Find the extension you'd like to import in the Visual Studio Marketplace. In this case [we are looking for GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens).
3. Review the version history in MarketPlace. In this case the April 2022 ver is not available (looks like only recent versions are retained). If this is the case, navigate to the [extension's GitHub repository](https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/releases?page=2) (if available) and find the version that aligns with the VS Code version (v12.0.6 in my case). In the assets section, download the .vsix file.
4. Open ADS, navigate to `Extensions`, right-click the ellipses at top-right of extensions bar, `install from vsix`, select the .vsix file you downloaded in step 3.